# How to write sql query for following

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table structure

[image]

I tried this before posting this question :

```
select x.col1,x.col2 from 
(
(select A from #t union all select C from #t) col1,
(select B from #t union all select D from #t) col2
)as x
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms180026.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
Select A,B FROM #T
UNION ALL
Select C,D FROM #T WHERE C is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it

```
SELECT T1.A AS A_or_C, T1.B AS B_or_D FROM table_name T1
UNION
SELECT T2.C AS A_or_C, T2.D AS B_or_D FROM table_name T2
```

just so it is absolutely clear.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
select A, B from TABLE union select C, D from TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A, B from table_name
union 
select C,D from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A as Name,B as Value FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT C,D FROM x 
WHERE C IS NOT NULL
```

The result will be:

```
NAME    VALUE
AA      0.5
BB      0.5
CC      0.3
DD      0.2
BB      0.3
CC      0.5
```

See Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f460/6)